# How to break this curse by a pure functional recursive function?

Tags: algorithm, scala

I have written two programs to find out a loopy path in a directed graphs.

The first version is a pure functional recursive solution, but its complexity is exponential. The second version following it achieves a linear complexity, but it doesn't look perfect either.

```
 def GetACycle(start: String, maps: Map[String, List[String]]): List[String] = {

    def explore(node: String, visits: List[String], steps: Int): List[String] = {
      println(List.fill(steps)("\t").mkString + node)
      if (visits.contains(node)) (visits.+:(node)).reverse
      else {
        if (maps(node).isEmpty) Nil
        else {
          val id = maps(node).indexWhere(x => !explore(x, visits.+:(node), steps + 1).isEmpty)
          if (id.!=(-1))
            explore(maps(node)(id), visits.+:(node), steps + 1)
          else
            Nil
        }
      }
    }

    explore(start, List(), 0)
  }
```

The second version uses mutable variables, the "visits" and "path", though it achieves a linear complexity in terms of number of visited nodes.

Would it be possible to achieve such a linear complexity in this situation while using a pure functional recursion without any mutable variables?

```
  def GetACycle2(start: String, maps: Map[String, List[String]]): List[String] = {
val nodes = maps.:\(Set[String]())((item, set) =>
  item._2.:\(set)(((i, set) => set.+(i))).+(item._1))
val pairs = nodes.toList.zip(List.fill(nodes.size)(false))

var visits = pairs.toMap
var path = List[String]()

def explore(node: String, steps: Int): Boolean = {
   println(List.fill(steps)("\t").mkString + node)
  path = path.+:(node)
  if (visits(node)) { visits = visits.updated(node, true); true }
  else {
    visits = visits.updated(node, true)
    if (maps(node).isEmpty) false
    else {
      maps(node).exists( x => explore(x, steps+1))
    }
  }
}

explore(start, 0)
path
```

}

Comment: `path = path.+:(node)` is very bad. Add values to the front of a list, and reverse it when you are finished.

Comment: Landei, you're right about it.

Comment: I just posted a more FP immutable answer on a related StackOverflow thread: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36144158/501113

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about something like this (Please excuse my style/form - As with the other poster, I'm not very familiar with coding in Scala either):

```
def GetACycle(start: String, maps: Map[String, List[String]]): List[String] = {

//entry function
def explore(node: String): List[String] = {
    explore_r(node, List(), List())
}

//main recursive
def explore_r(node: String, visited: List[String], path: List[String]): List[String] = {
    println(node)
    if (!maps.contains(node)) return Nil
    if (visited.contains(node)) return path++List(node)
    val branches = maps(node)
    for (nextnode <- branches){
        val loop = explore_r(nextnode, visited++List(node), path++List(node))
        if (loop != Nil) return loop
    }
    Nil
}
explore(start)
}
```

Comment: The key is using the RETURN to jump out of the recursion earlier.

Comment: @Qi Qi Glad I could help! To acknowledge Landei's comment to the original question, my solution should also be edited to prepend elements to the lists.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution in OCaml (I don't know Scala).

```
module M = Map.Make(String)

let rec loopy (graph: string list M.t) (node: string) (path_from_start: string list) (visited: string list M.t) =
  if M.mem node visited then
    (true, visited, path_from_start, M.find node visited)
  else
    let rec explore visited = function
    | [] -> (false, visited, [], [])
    | h :: t ->
      match loopy graph h (h::path_from_start) visited with
      | (true, _, _, _) as ans -> ans
      | (false, visited, _, _) -> explore visited t
    in
    explore (M.add node path_from_start visited) (M.find node graph)

let get_a_cycle (graph: string list M.t) (start: string) =
  match loopy graph start [start] (M.add start [start] M.empty) with
  | false, _, _, _ -> None
  | true, _, l1, l2 -> Some (List.rev_append l1 l2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The key is to using "return" keyword. Here is the improved version based on @Thomash and @tandem5 suggestions.

```
  def GetACycle_perfect(start: String, maps: Map[String, List[String]]): List[String] = {

def explore(node: String, visits: List[String], steps: Int): List[String] = {
  println(List.fill(steps)("\t").mkString + node)
  if (visits.contains(node)) (visits.+:(node)).reverse
  else {
    if (maps(node).isEmpty) Nil
    else {
      maps(node).foreach(v => {
        val loop = explore(v, visits.+:(node), steps + 1) 
        if (!loop.isEmpty) return loop
        })
      Nil
    }
  }
}
explore(start, List(), 0)
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem lately. The thing that bothers me in the above solution is, that the function explore is *not* tail recursive! This solution works of course for small trees, but if you have a large tree or - as in my case - a generated tree, you would have to come up with a solution with tail recursion. So, I wouldn't say that my solution is "perfect", but I think it would be worth a while (I also added a small main function so that others might test the code). The trick here is to use stacks (for backtracking) and an **exception** for the result (which might look a bit awkward - but isn't a loop kind of an exception?)

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayStack

object CheckCycle {
  def GetACycle(start: String, maps: Map[String, List[String]]): List[String] = {
    // the loop is returned in an exception
    case class ResultException(val loop: List[String]) extends Exception
    val visited = ArrayStack[String]()
    val branchesStack = ArrayStack[Iterator[String]]()

    def explore(node: String): List[String] = {
      try {
        // the "normal" result is Nil
        explore_tr(List(node).iterator)
      }
      catch {
        // the exceptional result is a loop
        case ResultException(loop) => loop
      }
    }

    @tailrec
    def explore_tr(branches: Iterator[String]): List[String] = {
      if (branches.hasNext) {
        val node = branches.next
        if (visited.contains(node)) {
          visited.push(node)
          // we found the loop
          throw new ResultException(visited.toList.reverse)
        }
        else
          maps.get(node) match {
            case None =>
              // go to siblings
              if (branches.hasNext) 
                 explore_tr(branches)
              else {
                  // track back
                  if (!branchesStack.isEmpty) {
                    visited.pop
                    explore_tr(branchesStack.pop)
                  }
                  else Nil // we're done
              }
            case Some(children) =>
              // go deeper
              visited.push(node)
              branchesStack.push(branches)
              explore_tr(children.iterator)
          }
      }
      else Nil
    }

    explore(start)
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    def maps = Map(
      "1" -> List("2", "3"),
      "2" -> List("4"),
      "3" -> List("4", "5"),
      "4" -> List("6", "1"))
    println(GetACycle("1", maps))
  }
}
```

Cheers Michael